# Removing Coveo insert options

Tags: coveo

Coveo adds a rule for insert options to add a new layout or MVC layout whenever you use Insert Item anywhere on the site. This is a little much for end-users, especially where I'm creating custom insert buttons in the experience editor for them and I don't want them creating these layouts. I looked in system/settings/rules but didn't see anything related. What's the best way to eliminate these? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The insert option is actually defined by a pipeline processor in `Coveo.UI.Controls.config`. You can remove it using the following config patch:

```
<processors>
  <uiGetMasters>
    <processor type="Coveo.UI.PipelineProcessors.GetMasters.AllowSearchPageProcessor, Coveo.UIBase">
      <patch:delete />
    </processor>
  </uiGetMasters>
</processors>
```

You can read more about this pipeline in this article about [Understanding the Coveo UI Pipelines](https://developers.coveo.com/x/wADnAQ)

Answer (score 4):

Coveo add those items to be easy for developers to play and discover Coveo for Sitecore. We do not add them through rules as upgrading Coveo for Sitecore would re-install the insert options. Instead we are using the `uiGetMasters` Sitecore processor in the `Coveo.UI.Controls.config` file. The exact node location is `/configuration/sitecore/processors/uiGetMasters` and the processor is:

```
<processor patch:before="*[starts-with(@type,'Sitecore.Pipelines.GetMasters.CheckSecurity')]" mode="on" type="Coveo.UI.PipelineProcessors.GetMasters.AllowSearchPageProcessor, Coveo.UIBase">
  <AllowSearchPageRootPath>/sitecore/Content</AllowSearchPageRootPath>
</processor>
```

Do not comment or remove it from that file as it will be replaced when you will upgrade Coveo for Sitecore. Instead, create a patch file to patch delete the node in your final Sitecore configuration.